# Upload a file using selenium webdriver WITHOUT using Robot API or selenium command send keys

Tags: java, file, selenium, upload

I have a web application which is using Outsystem for UI. So the File upload button is of Type = 'submit' and not Type='file' hence the selenium code

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("browse")).sendKeys("/path/to/the/file");
```

used to upload a file is not working for me. I have tried the code for Robot API as well

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("Browse"));
ele.click();    
StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(FilePath); 
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);                                     
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
Thread.sleep(500);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Which is sometimes working fine , but failing most of the time because the focus is removed from the window. My Script will run for a long time, in such scenario keeping the focus always on the window is not a feasible idea. Can someone suggest me any other way to tackle the upload file process in Selenium?

Comment: Before uploading the file, try to add explicit wait and then go with your code.

Comment: @jainishkapadia explicit wait on what ? i have few waits before the Robot is defined and after i click on enter. but when the file upload window opens how do i put wait on it? Is there any code to get the focus on the upload window?

Comment: Share your `HTML`

Comment: Did you try `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@type='submit']")).sendKeys("/path/to/the/file");` ?

Comment: @Mahipal i do not have issue in identifying the element. just that the code you mentioned does not work if the browse button is of type submit. It only works for traditional browse element which has type = file.

Comment: ok. Is it possible to share the url?

Comment: i cannot share the url , as it is not hosted yet. Let me share the HTML.            `code` <input id="idbutton" class="Button Button0" type="submit" tabindex="1062" value="Browse" name="namebrowse" onclick="$('#SWO_wt86_block_wtMainContent_SilkUIFramework_wt8_block_wtContent1_wtWBEntityInfo_SilkUIFramework_wtdata_block_wtColumn1_SilkUIFramework_wt120_block_wtContent_DropZone_wtdzCompanyRegistration_block_wtContainerFile').click(); window.location.href='#'; return false;"/>

Answer (score 0):

what i understand here is you are not able to wait till the upload window pop up appears as we can not give explicit wait for the window pop up, i resolved this issue by placing `Thread.sleep(2000)` just before you are initiating the Robot class so that pop up window can appear before we start doing work with it.